# Solutions to reduce start-up currents from multiple DC motors

Tags: dc-motor

I have some DC motors (8) which are connected to the same power supply (Murata, 12V, 20A), each motor needs 1A and is driven with a MOSFET. When I start these motors at the same time (a need for my application), I have a big start-up current. The voltage falls and the automatic over-current control of the power supply is triggered.

How can I properly start these motors at the same time? Does it need a bulk capacitor? Which size?

Comment: Capacitor value choice algorithm. Try a capacitor. While (supply is still getting triggered) try a bigger capacitor endWhile.

Comment: It is quite likely that using a capacitor to do this would require a super immense one. A better solution MAY be to stagger the turn on times - perhaps with as simple a solution as an RC filter in the gate drive. Better would be to add a small delay driving a Schmitt trigger which drive the gates  - with a slightly different delay in each gate drive.

Comment: To start motors at the same time is a need for my application. I already introduced a PID Regulation to softly reach my command but no ameliorations. (Motors are drived by PWM)

Comment: Are you able to ramp up the drive voltage? If you get them started spinning at a lower voltage and then ramp it up to the full voltage, it'll "spread out" the inrush pulse, giving you smaller inrush over a longer period instead of a huge spike.

Comment: Please take your commend about using PID regulation and add it to your question.  Are you ramping your command, or just hitting the motors with a step command?  It would be easy enough to design a feedback loop that has a faster time constant than the motor alone; if anything that would make your problem worse.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple simple ways of doing this. The most straightforward is to slowly ramp up the voltage from zero instead of applying 12V all at once; this "spreads out" your inrush pulse and makes it a lower current for a longer time.

---

If your power supply is fixed, however, one simple option is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7DOdY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There's a resistor to limit the current, along with a relay to short the resistor out when the motor is up to speed. This is similar to ramping up the voltage, as the resistor's resistance will reduce the voltage across the motor by an amount proportional to the motor current, and then the relay pulls the voltage the rest of the way up. The relay can also be any other type of switch that works for the currents and voltages needed; a MOSFET would be a perfectly acceptable choice as the application is DC.

---

You can also get what's called an inrush current limiter, which is simply a thermistor with a negative temperature coefficient. As current passes through the ICL, it heats up and its resistance drops, eventually balancing out with the motor current. You can also use an ICL in conjunction with a relay as above, which helps reduce the power lost in the ICL.

---

Note that relays used in this way do not necessarily need to be rated to break the full motor current. If you can ensure that the relays do not open while the motors are still spinning, you can use cheaper relays.

Answer (score 1):

You would ideally measure the inrush current of one motor.  Use a very-low value resistor in series with the (-) motor lead and use an oscilloscope.  What you are looking for is a current vs time curve.

Now decide how much voltage drop you can tolerate when the motors are starting.  You haven't provided any data about the power supply that you are using, so I'm going to make some assumptions.  You can change the numbers as required.

Let's say that your scope curve shows that the peak inrush current is 17 Amps and decreases to 2 Amps in 100 ms.  The change in current is 15 Amps.  Again: this is for a single motor only.

Now let's assume that the power supply will accommodate a drop in output voltage of 1 Volt before shutting down.  I may be way off here but, again, you can adjust the numbers to suit your specific situation.

Now choose an approximate capacitor value.  Delta I is 15 Amps.  Delta V is 1 Volt.  Delta T is 100 ms.

Now we are going to make some approximations.  A 1 Farad capacitor will have a voltage change of 1 Volt if a current of 1 Amp is drawn from the capacitor for 1 second.  Really simple relationship.

In your case, the current is not constant.  What we need to do is choose a capacitor value that results in a voltage change of 1V in 100ms.

I'm not going to do the math for you - holler if you need help with that.

Multiply that capacitor value by the total number of motors that you have.

This should get you in the ballpark.  Again: I'm pulling numbers out of the air because you did not provide any data about your specific devices.  But the above should help you make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what motion you need out of the motor.  DC motors driven by constant voltage draw more current the further away they are from their no-load speed; this means they'll draw a *lot* if they're stopped and you just switch on the voltage.  In fact, in that interval they draw stall current.

There's a few things you can do:

1. Limit the motor current individually.  Current-output amplifiers suitable for this sort of thing abound; if you don't know how to do that ask a separate question.
2. You mention that you're wrapping the motors with PID loops -- you could also ramp up the target motor velocity.
3. If the motors must be synchronized, give them all the maximum current command but then limit all the faster motors to match the slowest.
4. If you *really* want a control systems challenge, do the above, but reapportion more current to the slow motor -- but keep in mind that this is likely going to be a very difficult system to keep stable; I could see academic papers being written about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to limit the high starting current is to add an Inductor in series with the motors. The inductor will have to be of a high value (1 Henry or more). At the moment of starting the motors, it will prevent the high current. Soon it will work as a short circuit path. So, during running condition, it will not resist the flow of the current.

Comment: This is a useful concept but the inductors would have to be large and heavy if they aren't going to saturate.

Comment: Yes, you have to calculate the actual required value of the Inductor before you practically connect it to your circuit. Ferrite core inductors have high saturation values. I think they should work in this case.

Comment: Check the DC resistance of any "1 H" inductor before you buy it...